# Rcpp sugar commands in armadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying to use `ifelse()` command of Rcpp sugar with `arma::vec`. The code fails with error

`'ifelse' was not declared in this scope`

I could not find a solution. A simple example code (resulted with error) is below.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec f(arma::vec x, arma::vec y) {
  arma::vec res1 = Rcpp::ifelse(x < y, x, y);
  arma::vec res = trans(res1)*y;
  return res;
}

/*** R
f(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,1))
*/
```

Comment: You need to use `Rcpp::ifelse`, but this won't work with `arma::vec`.

Comment: @F. Privé  I edited the code according to your suggestion. Is there a way to use armadillo (for matrix computations) and rcpp sugar together?

Comment: I don't think so. Rcpp sugar is for Rcpp types.

Comment: C++ is a statically-typed object-oriented language. Something that works on one type (ie `Rcpp::NumericVector`) does not necessarily work on another (ie `arma::vec`).

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder if there is some commands to coerce the types like `as.double` or `as.data.frame` in `R`. For example `as.Numeric.Vector` here. But it seems there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Armadillo's [advanced constructors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col) you can have `Rcpp::NumericVector` and `arma::vec` that refer to the same memory location. Then you can use both `Rcpp` functions and `arma` functions by using the correct front-end object for that piece of memory:

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec f(Rcpp::NumericVector xr, Rcpp::NumericVector yr) {
  arma::vec x(xr.begin(), xr.size(), false, true); 
  arma::vec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false, true);
  Rcpp::NumericVector res1r(xr.size());
  arma::vec res1(res1r.begin(), res1r.size(), false, true);  
  res1r = Rcpp::ifelse(xr < yr, xr, yr);
  arma::vec res = trans(res1)*y;
  return res;
}

/*** R
f(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,1))
*/
```

I am not 100% sure that this does not have any unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I found I hope will work for you.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec f(arma::vec x, arma::vec y) {
  int n = x.size();
  arma::vec res(n); 
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if (x[i] < y[i]){res[i] = x[i];} else{res[i] = y[i];}
  }
  return trans(res)*y;
}
```

The output is

```
/*** R
f(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,1))
*/
     [,1]
[1,]    8
```

Comment: Please do NOT include `RcppArmadillo.h` _and_ `Rcpp.h`.  The former pulls in the latter.  You only need one, and order matters.   And what you show is redundant as well.

Comment: Making the corrections that Dirk proposes, edit my answer.

Comment: @Rafael Diaz thanks but your answer is not about my question.