# How to avoid deep copying when wrapping the arma::Mat<double> to Rcpp::NumericMatrix

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

```
NumericMatrix res = wrap(mat);// mat is an existing arma::Mat<double>
```

This is pretty expensive when matrix gets big and I don't need 'mat' object anymore once converted to Rcpp::NumericMatrix.

I've figured out how to steal the memory from arma::Mat, by

```
double * ptr = mat.memptr();
access::rw(mat.mem) = 0;
```

But the question is how to let R/Rcpp take over 'ptr' so that NumericMatrix is constructed directly from the existing memory?

Comment: We are effectively at the third implmentation of how Armadillo gets R objects and it should *not* be expensive.  See in `inst/examples/` for some timing exercises, and maybe try some at your end.  And on the way _in_ we clearly use the advancend constructor Arma.  Here, methinks, we would need to allocate _ensuring R's allocator gets used_ and then proxy to Armadillo for work returning the R object.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51578960/8416610 for an implementation  of @Dirk's idea to allocate with R and use Armadillo's advanced constructor. The reasoning is completely different, so no duplicate from my point of view ...

Comment: Thanks for both comments. The Armadillo matrix is returned by c++ lib and Rcpp doesn't know the exact size of it so can't allocate it at R/Rcpp side. My goal is to efficiently convert Armadillo mat to R matrix (not the other way around) (knowing that Armadillo mat is transient and won't be used after its coercion to R matrix)

Comment: Then unless I'm missing something, why not create the objects as `Rcpp::NumericMatrix`, then create `arma::mat` objects using the advanced constructor to operate on throughout your function a la @RalfStubner 's linked answer, then you can just return the original `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` objects at the end. I *think* that is what Dirk and Ralf were suggesting

Comment: @duckmayr As I understand it, Mike does not know the size of the matrix before the external function is called, making it impossible to have R allocate the required memory. I fear there is no way around copying the data in this case.

Comment: @RalfStubner I think I see now. I thought the lack of knowledge about matrix size was just when calling from R, but you mean the size cannot be computed until **after** various matrix calculations take place. Yeah, there may be no way around that.

Comment: Also, `memcpy` is cheap. As Daniel Lemire blogged just yesterday (https://lemire.me/blog/2020/01/14/how-fast-can-you-allocate-a-large-block-of-memory-in-c/) allocation may not be but for our _sciency_ workloads is that going to be the bottleneck?  If it is (Monte Carlo runs, say) you _could_ always preallocate chunks...